# Implementing a matrix of prices for different types

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, kotlin

```
Membership      || interest rate
Gold            || 0.12, 0.20, 0.3
Silver          || 0.13, 0.24, 0.3
Bronze          || 10.1, 0.2, 0.3

Membership      || value rate
Gold            || 10, 20, 30
Silver          || 10, 50, 40
```

In my app, I have some membership types. I want to calculate in advance all possible price combinations of the above and present in one object for each membership.

Let's say a user chooses Gold membership, I am looking to calculate every combination of **(value x interest rate)** and present to user in some object..

How can I implement this and what data structures, design can I use?

A user can select multiple membership if they wish in which case it should present all value/rate combination for both memberships.

I have something like this for example:

```
sealed class MembershipType(val label: String) {

    abstract val interestRates: List<BigDecimal>
    abstract val valueOptions: List<BigDecimal>


    object SILVER : MembershipType("Silver") {

        override val valueOptions: List<BigDecimal> =
                listOf<BigDecimal>(
                        BigDecimal.valueOf(10),
                        BigDecimal.valueOf(50),
                        BigDecimal.valueOf(40))
    }...
```

I have function that receives the list as follows:

```
fun calculateQuote(score: Int, memberShipSelected: List<MembershipType>): Quote {//TODO}
```

For each membership type in list, extract the value and rate and calculate all possible combinations.

Combinations For GOLD

```
        rates
Values   0.12       0.20            0.3
10      10*0.12     10*0.20         10*0.3
20      20*0.12     20*0.20         20*0.3
30      30*0.12     30*0.20         30*0.3
```

Comment: Give an example of all combinations calculation. For Gold only and for Gold and Silver.

Comment: @EldarAgalarov - added combinations for Gold. how to represent the result in some object for each MembershipType?

Comment: Ok, look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i don't know what exactly calculation logic do you need. But I'm providing example, how you can do it:

```
data class Result(val value: BigDecimal, val rate: BigDecimal, val result: BigDecimal)

sealed class Membership {

    abstract val interestRates: List<BigDecimal>
    abstract val valueOptions: List<BigDecimal>

    fun calcCombinations() = this.valueOptions.map { vo ->
        this.interestRates.map {
            Result(vo, it, vo * it)
        }
    }

    object SILVER : Membership() {
        override val interestRates = listOf(BigDecimal("0.13"), BigDecimal("0.24"), BigDecimal("0.3"))

        override val valueOptions = listOf(BigDecimal(10), BigDecimal(50), BigDecimal(40))
    }

    object GOLD : Membership() {

        override val interestRates = listOf(BigDecimal("0.12"), BigDecimal("0.2"), BigDecimal("0.3"))

        override val valueOptions = listOf(BigDecimal(10), BigDecimal(20), BigDecimal(30))
    }
}

object Main {

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println(GOLD.calcCombinations())
        println(SILVER.calcCombinations())

        val membershipToCombinations = setOf(GOLD, SILVER).associateBy({
            it
        }, {
            it.calcCombinations()
        })

        println(membershipToCombinations[SILVER])
        println(membershipToCombinations[GOLD])
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me understand `associatedBy()`. This however would not tell me about which value/rate combination the result is of so I lose that info. Can we capture in a object, with properties, `value`, `rate`, `result` ?